# Clojurescript - invoking promises from native module correctly

Tags: node.js, react-native, clojurescript

I'm new to Clojurescript. I'm trying to invoke a function in a java based react native module. All native modules return promises in react native and I'm trying to get the ClojureScript bit right but I get a message from Node during compilation that "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection..." . I guess Node thinks that the JS produced from Clojurescript doesn't have the 'reject' clause.

My code looks like this:

```
(when platform/android?
     (try
       (->
         ((.-isAvailable RNTextDirection)) ;1st native module function
         (.then
           (fn [value]
             (when value
               (->
                 ((.-isRTL RNTextDirection) text)  ;2nd native module function
                 (.then (fn [value] ( (or value (right-to-left-text? text) (assoc :rtl? true))))
                 (.catch (fn [error] ( (right-to-left-text? text) (assoc :rtl? true))))))))
         (.catch (fn [error] ( (right-to-left-text? text) (assoc :rtl? true)))))
       (catch js/Object err ( (right-to-left-text? text) (assoc :rtl? true))))))
```

Can anyone help me understand what's missing here? Thanks!

Comment: I am asking this without any clue what is going on: are you sure the double parens around `((.-isAvailable RNTextDirection))`; is what you want - it will execute the result of `.-isAvailable` which sounds pretty predicatish to me ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with React Native from CLJS, but it seems like you `(.catch ...)` both promise chains where failure is possible, implying the warning is spurious. I would be more suspect of how Node performs the check for unhandled rejection than than the CLJS compiler isn't producing all your function calls. It may be there's a layer of indirection from the CLJS runtime that prevents Node from realizing that the potential rejection is handled.